# Return a string using the month part of a date field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a query which populates the `salesPeriod` field from the `salesDate` field. The query should return a `string value` based on the date part of the `salesDate`. The conditions are:

`If month is equal to equal to 11, 12, 1, return "Christmas Sales"`

`If month is equal to 6,7,8  return "Summer sales".`
`Otherwise return return "N/A"`

Perhaps something like:

`salesPeriod: DatePart("month",[salesDate])) = 11 Or 12 Or 1)....` or any direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `month()` function and conditional logic.  Here is one method:

```
select iif(month(salesDate) in (11, 12, 1), "Christmas Sales",
           iif(month(salesDate) in (6, 7, 8), "Summer sales", "N/A")
          ) as salesPeriod
```

Comment: this method is nice and swift. Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend the `MONTH()` function, which in addition to the other answer can be implemented using the `CASE` statement.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
    WHEN MONTH(salesDate) in (11, 12, 1)
        THEN 'Christmas Sales',
    WHEN MONTH(salesDate) in (6, 7, 8)
        THEN 'Summer sales'
    ELSE 
        'N/A'
    END) AS 'Sales Period'
```

Comment: . . MS Access doesn't support `case`.  I assume the upvoter also ignored the database tag.